# Copying shapefile data into file geodatabase using R?

Tags: shapefile, r, file-geodatabase

I have one file geodatabase (`*.gdb`) and one shapefile (`*.shp`).

How can I copy that shapefile data into the file geodatabase using R?

Comment: Check if rgdal::ogrDrivers includes this format for write, but I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

If you have gdal built with the filegdb plugin then this is possible through rgdal, or by just using the command line tool ogr2ogr. If on windows, the website gisinternals has ready built versions of gdal and the filegdb plugin